# Access DLLs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dll, serial-port

I need to read the serial port as an input for a web based application.

I know that the browser can't do it, but if I build a DLL and send it to my client, can I access this DLL and read the serial port with JavaScript or I will need something like ActiveX?

Comment: If you need to do this you are using the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active X Control will be able to access the serial port.

Here is a link on how to create one and access it through JavaScript

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/writinganactivexcontrolincsharp.aspx

(You don't need .net to write it, but this is what the example uses).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript cannot (and should not) call DLLs due to security issues.

You should be looking at ActiveX

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use JNI within a Java applet. This may be an alternative to ActiveX, but the little I know about it, this technique may be a pain.

Comment: Well it's possible to do it with Java in general, but from an applet inside a web browser the security manager won't allow it.

Comment: You would need a signed applet. That's where the pain is.